# UWP How to Configure Application Packaging Project for different clients in VisualStudio 2019

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2019, desktop-bridge

I have a WPF project called ProjectX which contains one file config.txt.  I am using "Application Packaging Project" to build installable package.

```
   ProjectX  Original(config.txt)
  |------|-------|
  |              |
Client X1      Client X2
config.txt     config.txt
```

I have made two Application Packaging Project, One for each client. Now what I want to do is replace original Config.txt file with client specific config.txt in Application Packaging Project.  I tried creating this file in packaging project and setting Build Action as "Content" and "Copy Always", I thought it will override original file, but that does not work as expected.  Is my approach correct?  or are there better alternative ways of doing this ?

Please Advise.
Regards

Comment: Does the new file appear anywhere in the package? I believe WAP puts things in a sub-directory. You can rename the .MSIX as .ZIP to see what is inside.